# Помогите разобраться в коде на Си

Tags: c

Программа для поиска автоморфных чисел среди первых 25 чисел. Что делает в программе цикл while?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//1, 5, 6, 25,

int main()
{   int res;
    long int no;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
        no = i;
        long int square = no * no;
        res = 1;
        while (no > 0 && square > 0) {
            if (no % 10 != square % 10) {
                res = 0;
            }
            no = no / 10;
            square = square / 10;
        }
        if (res == 1) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

И почему если его убрать, то в консоли выведутся числа:1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15 , 16, 20, 21, 25, хотя эти числа и так подходили под условие if на 13 строчке при существующем цикле while

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: все исправил. :)

Comment: Да просто проверяет, заканчивается ли квадрат числа самим числом — поциферно, так сказать... Смотрит цифры с конца числа. Кстати, после `res=0;` стоило бы поставить `break` :)

Comment: спасибо !!!!! ♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл позволяет перебрать **все** цифры числа `no` (кстати, `&& square > 0` в условии можно убрать), а не только последнюю.

Вот у вас выводится, например, 15, хотя это не автоморфное число  - совпадения одной последней цифры недостаточно.

А 25 - автоморфное, т.к. в цикле проверяется, то последняя цифра квадрата 5, и предпоследняя 2

Comment: большое спасибо, вы очень помогли начинающему программисту!!!